# Php foreach function problems

Tags: php, foreach

I have a trouble with foreach function in php. I search some tutorial but still cant understand how it works. Please somebody help me.

I have a `textarea` string like this, this string is `$g_userselect`.

```
+----------------+
| 1000|10        |
| 2000|40        |
| 3000|80        |
+----------------+
```

I would like to separate it into my `<form><select>` function.

```
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="1000">Cost 10</option>
  <option value="2000">Cost 40</option>
  <option value="3000">Cost 80</option>
</select>
```

I do like this:

```
$data=explode("\n",$g_userselect);
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    list($value['quantity'], $value['select']) = split ('|', $data);
}
```

And loop like this:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
<!--{loop $data $value}-->
<option value="{$value[quantity]}">Cost {$value[select]}</option>
<!--{/loop}--></select>
```

But only show to me as:

```
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does it really have the box around it?

Comment: What is `{loop $data $value}`? Smarty? You didn't mention any template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do another simple explode to get the 2 halves of each line.

You would also be getting issues as your foreach creates a variable called `$value` and your `list()` was attampting to load data to an array called `$value`. The `$value` created by the foreach look is transient, i.e. reused each time round the foreach loop.

```
$newvalues = array();
$data=explode("\n",$g_userselect);
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $bits = explode('|',$value);
    $t = array('quantity' => $bits[0], 'select' => $bits[1]);
    $newvalues[] = $t;
}
print_r($newvalues);
```

Gives this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [select] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [select] => 2000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 3
            [select] => 3000
        )

)
```

> WARNING: split() is deprecated as of PHP5.3

Comment: Since split() is deprecated as of PHP5.3, so I try your answer, and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

When you want to change the value of an array inside `foreach`,
you need to loop over its reference:

```
$data=explode("\n",$g_userselect);
foreach ($data as $key => &$value){
    list($value['quantity'], $value['select']) = explode('|', $value);
}
```

Notice the `&` before `$value`.

You must split `$value` instead of `$data` and better use `explode()` there, too, because `split()` is `DEPRECATED`since PHP 5.3

Answer (score -1):

```
$g_userselect = array('1000|10', '2000|40', '3000|80');
foreach ($g_userselect as $k => $v){
    $a = explode('|', $v);
    $options = "<option value=$a[0]>Cost $a[1]</option>";

}
```

**HTML :**

```
<select name="select" id="select">
<?=$options ?>
</select>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="1000">Cost 10</option>
  <option value="2000">Cost 40</option>
  <option value="3000">Cost 80</option>
</select>
```